# How do i access query string in flash action script 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In as2 it was very easy to access query string just using _root, but this doesn't seem to work on as3.

```
<embed src="loaderInfoExample.swf?a=123" quality="high" bgcolor="#0000ff" width="250" height="50" name="loaderInfoExample" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

How do i access value of a? I tried it with _root as well as in flash client tried this :-

```
userNameTextField.text=root.loaderInfo.parameters.a;
```

But both doesn't seem to work. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. Try using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to include your flash content correctly and pass the parameter as the *flashvars* part.

Btw. you also should add some check routine to make sure that `root.loaderInfo.parameters.a` is not `null`, because assigning `null` to a TextField's `text` attribute produces an error.

Comment: But it's auto generated code from Flash. Where do i include it in here? Also object tag should always work why should i use SWFObject? QueryStrings should be accessible in object tag also?
The autogenerated code is huge about 320 lines long. :(

Comment: If you are using the standard autogenerated code to show your flash content, make sure you pass the flash vars with a new `param` tag for the `object` tag. See [this page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

look below in the autogenerated code you have to add the FlashVar there as well in order for it to work

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 AC_FL_RunContent(
  'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0',
  'width', '550',
  'height', '400',
  'src', 'deleteme',
  'quality', 'high',
  'pluginspage', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer',
  'align', 'middle',
  'play', 'true',
  'loop', 'true',
  'scale', 'showall',
  'wmode', 'window',
  'devicefont', 'false',
  'id', 'deleteme',
  'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
  'name', 'deleteme',
  **'FlashVars', 'tester=test',**
  'menu', 'true',
  'allowFullScreen', 'false',
  'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
  'movie', 'deleteme',
  'salign', ''
  ); //end AC code
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that when you're movie is at least **inited**,

e.g:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, paramsReady);

function paramsReady(event:Event):void{
userNameTextField.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.a;
}
```

Comment: doesn't help :(.

<embed src="loaderInfoExample.swf" FlashVars = "a=123" quality="high" bgcolor="#0000ff" width="250" height="50" name="loaderInfoExample" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
 <PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="a=123">
This is my flash code
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, paramsReady);
function paramsReady(event:Event):void{
userNameTextField.text=this.loaderInfo.parameters.a;
}
i get error parameter text must be not null. :(

Comment: Interestingly when i deleted all autogenerated code and placed simple object tag as :-
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/loaderInfoExample.html

It works fine!! :):) Now i want to know is there a bug in autogenerated code from flash cs4? i just clicked publish and 300 lines of code got generated and the same query string is not working in that object tag whereas it's working in simple object tag.